# Showing unicode character in R

Tags: r, unicode, xlsx

Using read_excel function, I read an excel sheet which has a column that contains data in both English and Arabic language.

English is shown normally in R. but Arabic text is shown like this <U+0627><U+0644><U+0639><U+0645><U+0644>

```
dataset <- read_excel("Dataset_Draft v1.xlsx",skip = 1 )
dataset %>% select(description)
```

[image: Result]

I tried `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")` but with no success.
I want to show Arabic text normally and I want to make filter on this column with Arabic value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the `read.xlsx()` function from the `xlsx` library.
Here you can specify an encoding.

```
data <- xlsx::read.xlsx("file.xlsx", encoding="UTF-8")
```

Comment: Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE","arabic") also work for read_excel function.